# How to expand a tree view using AutoIt

Tags: autoit

The UI is as following:
[image]

The tool "AutoIt Window Info" can only locate the elements in red (red rectangle area), the sub items can not be located.
So how can I expand or operate these items？

Comment: If it's a common TreeView32 control you can use the [ControlTreeView](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlTreeView.htm) function. As your control class is SysTreeView32 that should most likely work...

Answer (score 1):

Usually Windows controls can be accessed using keystrokes as well.

In the screen-dump the Farmtt element is selected. That would be your starting point.

You may try:

- Send("{DOWN}")   Move down an element.
- Send("{TAB}")    Navigate to next control (button, checkbox, etc)
- Send("{NumPadMult}") Recursively expands folders in a SysTreeView32.
- Send("{ENTER}")  ENTER key on the main keyboard

etc.

Reference:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm

Comment: Using these hotkeys in trees can be troublesome if there are load times when a node is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things over here:
1) Use the following code snippet:

```
;Gets the handle for the text
Func readFirstlevelTreeNodes($hWndCtrl)
   Local $firstItemHandle = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetFirstItem ($hWndCtrl)
   Local $iCount = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetSiblingCount( $hWndCtrl, $firstItemHandle )
   Dim $aRet[$iCount]
   $aRet[0] = $firstItemHandle
   For $index = 1 To $iCount - 1
      $aRet[$index] = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetNextSibling ( $hWndCtrl, $firstItemHandle )
      $firstItemHandle = $aRet[$index]
   Next

   getTreeNodeTextList($hWndCtrl,$aRet)
EndFunc

; Gets the text for given sibling node handle lists
Func getTreeNodeTextList($hWndCtrl,$aRet)
   ConsoleWrite("Tree Node first level list"&@CRLF)
   For $index = 0 To Ubound($aRet) -1
      ConsoleWrite(_GUICtrlTreeView_GetText ( $hWndCtrl, $aRet[$index] )&@CRLF)
   Next
EndFunc
```

You may see the output for the first level tree nodes.

2) If you still dont see the output then please verify the control handle values and window handles. If they are correct and it still doesnt show the first level tree nodes then try running your sciTE editor as administrator.

I think this should help.